# Docker manager autostarting containers

Tags: linux, docker

Docker daemon autostarts some services on my machine whenever it boots up. How do I manage the list of services to be started automatically by the docker daemon?

Comment: If you are talking about containers that start up when you start your docker daemon starts up, All your services here have a restart policy that is attached with your container metadata. Have you checked that? 
Had a look here?
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni I usually start docker services by doing `docker-compose up`. Do I have to check the `docker-compose.yml` files for restart policies? Does docker have a registry where it stores the containers to start?

Comment: ```docker inspect <container_name> ``` will let you know the restart policy of the running container. There are multiple policies you can attach to containers when you  run them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Running docker containers have a restart policy to them. This is given to it by when running them and can be seen in the **container metadata** You can check if your services have them by

```
docker inspect <container_name>
```

**Docker currently has four restart policies:**

1. no
2. on-failure
3. unless-stopped
4. always

You can choose to update it for a running service by :

`docker update --restart=no <container_name>`

Answer (score 0):

Update the restart policy of containers with this command:

```
docker update --restart=no <containers>...
```